# How to display individual datas in mysql through jquery autocomplete

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, autocomplete

I am having a problem here
I want to display the datas in DB using autocomplete
But when I search in the textbox it is showing everything
for example

```
c++javaphpcoldfusionjavascriptaspruby
```

but what I want is

```
"c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"
```

here is my code

Controller

```
 function get_ingredients() {
          $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

             $this->load->model("save_datas");
        $data["show_ingre"] = $this->save_datas->select_ingredient();
        $this->load->view("view_home", $data);
    }
```

View

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
                    source: ["<?php
foreach ($show_ingre as $ingre) {
    echo "$ingre->ingredient";
}
?>"]


                    });
                });
        </script>

   <?php echo form_open('home/save_input'); ?>
        <input type="text" name="ingredient" id="autocomplete" /><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
        <?php form_close(); ?>
```

Model

```
function select_ingredient() {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT ingredient FROM ingredients");
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The view file is messed up. Take a look at your pages source code. It should be something like this:

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
         source: ["c++javaphpcoldfusionjavascriptaspruby"]
     });
 });
 </script>
```

I think you should be able to see the problem here. Anyways, if you didn't, here's the code to fix it:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: [<?php
        foreach ($show_ingre as $ingre) {
            echo '"' . $ingre->ingredient . '", ';
        }
        ?>]
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the problem is the same. It is still showing everything in the database :(